# Is there any way to get the SMS Opt-Outs rate in account level?

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, automation

Our client want to know sms opt out rate in account level, so that based on results they can plan campaign volume/KPIs.

Let me know is there any OOB features in MC? If no, Kindly let me know feasible solution?

Answer (score -1):

Please check these OOB reports in Analytics Builder which might help you :

SMS Account Summary
SMS Deactivation Summary
SMS Message Detail Report
SMS Message Summary